# Turning the dark mode on for different elements of the webpage

Tags: html, css, darkmode

I can actually switch the dark and light modes on my webpage, but some elements can't change their own color in spite of the Javascript code I've written. The JS function executes after clicking on a certain SVG image.

The color of the div where the SVG icon and input field are placed does not change. The color of the input changes only to dark mode.

```js
function SearchBarColor(color, bool) {
  var seek = document.getElementsByClassName("input-container");
  var searchbar = document.getElementsByClassName("searchbar");
  var idx;
  if (bool == true) idx = 0;
  else idx = 1;

  if (color == "white") {
    seek[idx].style.backgroundColor == "#1D1932";
    searchbar[idx].style.backgroundColor = "#1D1932";
  } else if (color == "#1D1932") {
    seek[idx].style.backgroundColor == "white";
    searchbar[idx].style.backgroundColor == "white";
  }
}

function TheObject(m, bool) {
  if (m.style.backgroundColor == "white") {
    m.style.backgroundColor = "#1d1932";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#131129";
    document.getElementById("mode").src = "./SVG/mode.svg";
    SearchBarColor("white", bool);
  } else if (m.style.backgroundColor != "white") {
    m.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#F2F2F2";
    document.getElementById("mode").src = "./SVG/mode2.svg";
    SearchBarColor("#1D1932", bool);
  }
}

function ChangetoOpposite() {
  let width = screen.width;
  var m = document.getElementById("menu");
  var m2 = document.getElementById("menu-mobile");
  if (width <= 425) {
    var widthbool = false;
    TheObject(m2, widthbool);
  } else if (width >= 1440) {
    var widthbool = true;
    TheObject(m, widthbool);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="desktop-searchbar">
      <div class="input-container">
        <img class="icon" src="./SVG/Search.svg" />
        <input type="text" class="searchbar" placeholder="Search Here" />
      </div>
      <ul class="ul-bell-mode-avatar">
        <li>
          <img src="./SVG/mode2.svg" onclick="ChangetoOpposite()" id="mode" />
        </li>
        <li><img src="./SVG/bell.svg" id="bell" /></li>
        <li><img src="./img/avatar.png" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mobile-searchbar">
      <img src="./SVG/Logo.svg" />
      <div class="input-container">
        <img class="icon" src="./SVG/Search.svg" />
        <input type="text" class="searchbar" placeholder="Search Here" />
      </div>
      <ul class="ul-bell-mode-avatar">
        <li>
          <img src="./SVG/mode2.svg" onclick="ChangetoOpposite()" id="mode" />
        </li>
        <li><img src="./SVG/bell.svg" id="bell" /></li>
        <li><img src="./img/avatar.png" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be interested in the CSS only solution: `@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){}` - you can define all styling in there and its toggled by the users settings on their system.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. I made a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]